# Windows 10 OpenSSH Client not found in non-admin console

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, permissions, path

I'm having trouble using the built-in OpenSSH client from a regular command prompt.  The client got automatically installed as part of Windows 10 Update 1803.

When I try to execute it from a regular command prompt, I get the following:

```
C:\>ssh
'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

As if it couldn't find it in the path, however the directory ***is*** in the path (output shortened for brevity):

```
C:\>path
PATH=[...];%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;[...]
```

And if I `cd` into the folder directly, the command works:

```
C:\>cd %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\

C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH>ssh
usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
           [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address]
           [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           destination [command]
```

### As administrator

Interestingly, if I launch the command prompt as Administrator, the command works (as expected) from any directory:

```
C:\>ssh
usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
           [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address]
           [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           destination [command]
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the client from the *Manage optional features* section of the Settings app, but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I changed `%systemroot%\system32\openssh` to `%systemroot%\System32\OpenSSH`, and it's OK for me now.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I had to use small letters for the variable, so I replaced `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH` by `%systemroot%\System32\OpenSSH` and it worked.